Why does the OpenRewrite ChangeKey/ChangeValue seem to have really bad performance when using KeyPath? Is there an alternative?
I have the following recipes I run from a parent recipe...
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeKey:
      oldKeyPath: $.['resilience4j.retry'].configs.*[?(@.maxRetryAttempts)]
      newKey: maxAttempts
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeKey:
      oldKeyPath: $.resilience4j.retry.configs.*[?(@.maxRetryAttempts)]
      newKey: maxAttempts
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeKey:
      oldKeyPath: $.['resilience4j.retry'].configs.*[?(@.max-retry-attempts)]
      newKey: max-attempts
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeKey:
      oldKeyPath: $.resilience4j.retry.configs.*[?(@.max-retry-attempts)]
      newKey: max-attempts

I notice this increases the run-time by a lot compared to any other test when I have a sizeable amount of yaml files. I also see another one that seems to take a while...
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeValue:
      keyPath: $.spec.template.spec.containers.env[?(@.name == 'SERVER_TOMCAT_INTERNAL_PROXIES')].name
      value: SERVER_TOMCAT_REMOTEIP_INTERNAL_PROXIES

This is confirmed by data tables suggesting these recipes are taking the longest in terms of total edit time.
This seems through testing to anecdotally be the bottleneck. Can someone confirm that these recipes do not scale well? I know there are options like pre-conditions and markers to make this more efficient but are they the right way to go?
Also we do have recipes that do not use keyPath like
  - org.openrewrite.java.spring.ChangeSpringPropertyKey:
      oldPropertyKey: "spring.data.cassandra.provider-ref"
      newPropertyKey: "spring.cassandra.provider-ref"

That do not affect performance but they don't have KeyPath.
I am using the maven-rewrite plugin to run these recipes.
Here is a screenshot of the DT

Update
So based off my original hunch that a precondition was the way to go. However, seeing that this was a fairly complicated YAML Path expression I thought maybe I could just search all the files for the text before the expression so
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeKey:
      oldKeyPath: $.['resilience4j.retry'].configs.*[?(@.max-retry-attempts)]
      newKey: max-attempts
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeKey:
      oldKeyPath: $.resilience4j.retry.configs.*[?(@.max-retry-attempts)]
      newKey: max-attempts

Was changed to add
@Value
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class FindFilesContaining extends Recipe {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FindFilesContaining.class);

    transient SourcesFiles results = new SourcesFiles(this);

    @Option(displayName = "String to contain",
            description = "A String that needs to be contained in the file",
            required = true,
            example = "this is the string")
    @Nullable
    String searchString;

    ...

    @Override
    public TreeVisitor<?, ExecutionContext> getVisitor() {
        return new TreeVisitor<Tree, ExecutionContext>() {

            @Override
            public @Nullable Tree visit(@Nullable Tree tree, ExecutionContext ctx) {
                if (tree instanceof SourceFile) {
                    SourceFile sourceFile = (SourceFile) tree;
                    Path sourcePath = sourceFile.getSourcePath();
                    try {
                        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(sourcePath));
                        assert searchString != null;
                        if (content.contains(searchString)) {
                            log.warn("Found file: " + sourcePath);
                            results.insertRow(ctx, new SourcesFiles.Row(sourcePath.toString(),
                                    tree.getClass().getSimpleName()));
                            return SearchResult.found(sourceFile);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Error reading file: " + sourcePath, e);
                    }
                }
                return tree;
            }
        };
    }
}
preconditions:
  - org.me.FindFilesContaining:
      searchString: "max-retry-attempts"
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeKey:
      oldKeyPath: $.['resilience4j.retry'].configs.*[?(@.max-retry-attempts)]
      newKey: max-attempts
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.ChangeKey:
      oldKeyPath: $.resilience4j.retry.configs.*[?(@.max-retry-attempts)]
      newKey: max-attempts

This seems to work but I can also see where a REALLY large file could blow this up. That being said it does seem to drastically reduce the time the dryrun takes. But this also seems like a bad precondition since it reads the whole file but it seems way faster than serializing all the yamls. Any thoughts?

Surprising to hear about considerable time spent in the recipe run; usually it's building up the model of your code that takes far longer than any recipe execution. Helpful that you already used the data tables to pinpoint the recipe execution duration. Would you mind logging an issue with your findings?
If indeed considerable time is spent parsing yaml files that are unlikely to contain the keys you're after then a FindSourceFiles precondition could be a great way to limit which files are evaluated to speed up performance today.

No it is after building things up because I see the [INFO] Running recipe(s)... before it goes out to lunch. I am spending some time adding recipes one by one to see if there is some sort of pattern that is causing the issue but that will take time. As for the precondition as I mentioned that is what I am looking to understand more about like a link to a good example spec for those recipes. I also want to know if that is really the correct way or if it is to create a bunch of markers before it starts then filter on those.

Also specifically I can see the ChangeKey ones add like 20-30 mins but I see some taking even longer to run. I will provide more info when I can

Also added the datatable for perspective

Thanks for the ideas I came up with one precondition that works but seems like it might be a trap. Can you take a look?

Looks ok, but is there any reason you could not use https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/text/find  instead of the custom FindFilesContaining?

I don't see "FindFilesContaining" in the code base can you link to the source you are referring to?

Use this instead: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/text/find

the problem is that spring, etc use this recipe so even if I call theirs there is an issue

Hmm; suppose you're right; then the next step would be to see if we can improve performance of that matcher. Any help there appreciated!

Knut dove in and came up with quite some performance improvements already: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/compare/5aea1f47c701417766e5d04b7a21e877077b985b...f2b923248e2692a3d35bdff15285be256cfd69b6
You should see improvements on the next release, or you can try out our snapshot versions

I will give it a shot when I get a sec thank you!

Sure! Just finished up a new round of patch releases, including the CLI. hope that helps!
